# PHP-FPM: dont get all errors returned

Tags: php, nginx

Im using nginx 1.4.1 and php 5.4.17 with FPM.

I have a simple app running fine until i include a file having the following content:

```
class Config {
  const HELLO = array('WORLD');
}
```

My PHP doesnt give me any error on this file when i execute it on my command line using php-cgi oder php. But online parser tell me arrays with const are not allowed within classes.
But why is nginx and php not returning this error?

The pool in php-fpm for this app runs on a unix socket, accessing any other php file or html file works fine.
catch_worker_output=yes is set and display_errors is set TO STDERR so nginx is getting the error, so i only need to look into the error log file written by nginx.
My acces log gives me HTTP Status 200.

But still i get a blank page, no output at all, no errors in nginx error log or in php error log even my command line tool doesnt give me errors when i test that php file.

i have set SCRIPT_FILE to $document_root&fast_cgi_script in my location block for .php files for the server block.

If i put some non existent function name like "idonotexist(true);" then i get a fatal error on my browser telling my that function doesnt exist. So what is the problem here?

**UPDATE**: on my server running this on console returns nothing, so that php code is ok:

```
php -r "class Config { const HELLO = array('WORLD'); }"
```

BUT running this on my other server having simple apx apache based php-module i get this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Arrays are not allowed in class constants in Command line code on line 1
Fatal error: Arrays are not allowed in class constants in Command line code on line 1
```

so something is wrong with my nginx/php-fpm config

**UDATE 2**: i managed to get the command line version to work fine by putting this to php.ini

```
error_reporting = 2147483647
```

instead of

```
error_reporting = 999999
```

but still via nginx/php-fpm i get a blank page.
i now simply created a test.php having only that Config class definition with that wrong const usage. Commandline works now printing the correct fatal error but nothing via nginx/php-fpm.

Comment: ah darn it. i fixed it.
i fixed it by adding php_admin_value[error_reporting] = 2147483647 into my php-fpm.conf pool configuration. now it works via fpm too. so main problem was my error_reporint was wrong.